# Software not using/finding OpenGL 3.3 drivers

Tags: system, graphic-drivers, drivers, graphics

ANY software I install on the system cannot access my OpenGL drivers for whatever reason. Most software uses OpenGL 3.3 and I have exactly that -- OpenGL 3.3, and I checked too! Running `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` shows that my drivers are compatible with OpenGL 3.3

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce G105M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 340.107
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 340.107
OpenGL shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 NVIDIA 340.107 340.107
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

No matter what I do, I always get this error whilst running software that uses OpenGL 3.3 :

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Failed to create the opengl context. Check your drivers support openGL 3.3. Hint: opensource drivers don't
```

I tried searching online to no avail, so I must turn to this forum for help. Any and all help (that doesn't corrupt my system drivers, haha ️) would be appreciated

glxinfo | grep -i OpenGL as per T0ba's request:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce G105M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 340.107
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 340.107
OpenGL shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 NVIDIA 340.107 340.107
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be uninstalling the official Nvidia drivers. My PC is perfectly compatible with these drivers, however, it turns out that there is some sort of magical problem with the drivers, and uninstalling them worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install mesa packages:

```
apt install mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-utils mesa-utils-extra
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work... do you have any other answers? The effort is still appreciated!️

Comment: @YaBoiChipsAhoy Run "glxinfo | grep -i opengl" in terminal and show the result.

Comment: Ok I will edit the post